How can we get a large Response Body by performing Network Interception using WebDriver DevTools?
My code looks like this:
        devTool.addListener(Network.responseReceived(), responseReceieved -> {


            String responseURL = responseReceieved.getResponse().getUrl();
            RequestId resquestId = responseReceieved.getRequestId();
            if(responseURL.contains("https://xxx")) {
                
                System.out.println("Response Headers => " + responseReceieved.getResponse().getHeaders().toString());

                System.out.println("Response MIME Type => " + responseReceieved.getResponse().getMimeType().toString());
                System.out.println("Response body => " + responseReceieved.getResponse());

                System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Response body: " +devTool.send(Network.getResponseBody(resquestId)).getBody());
            }
        });

        driver.get("http://testXXXXX.com");

        try {

            Thread.sleep(5000);

        } catch(InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        driver.quit();

But after running this, I am getting error as below:
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevToolsException:
{"id":71,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"No resource with given identifier found"},"sessionId":"8ACF1FEA230D3BBC755C865CF377A23C"}
Build info: version: '4.18.0', revision: 'b6bf9de7cc*'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.sendAndWait(Connection.java:193)

